# Missing Api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll on Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 7 and I'm not capable to run any programs because of missing Api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-**1**.dll, independently which of the target platform version I choose (Available are 8.1 and 10).

In my folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs, only version l1-1-**0**.dll is available. I tried out different Windows Kit 10 versions, but the required api dll's were not available.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
1.) How can I bring VS2015 to use older versions of Api-ms-win-core-**.dlls or
2.) How can I update my existing Api-ms-win-core-*.dlls to newer versions?

Thank you for any responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your code with the `Visual Studio 2015 – Windows XP (v140_xp)` platform toolset to [generate code which is compatible for Windows XP/Vista/7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx).

[Based on your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368490/missing-api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1-dll-on-visual-studio-2015-under-win/47368792#comment81714931_47368792) I see you used the `qt-opensource-windows-x86-winrt-msvc2015-5.7.0.exe` which is for [Store Based apps](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/winrt-support.html). So this explains why you get a message that dependency files are not found.

Install the non WinRT files of QT to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately I can't choose Windows 7 for Target Platform Version (only Windows 8.1 and 10). Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp) is not compatible with Target Platform Version 8.1 or 10.

Comment: in VS2015 setup install the Windows 8.1 SDK and the XP compiler

Comment: Ah I didn't see that option. This could be one solution to my problem then.

Comment: Hm the XP compiler checkbox is already checked.... This was already a default setting.

Comment: post a picture of your platform configuration

Comment: I'm getting closer. Windows XP (v140_xp) is compatible with Target Platform Version 8.1. I had to clear a Preprocessor definition. I also see now, why the Api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll is required. It's a dependency of my used Qt dll. Thank you for your help!

Comment: ok, post it s answer which QT dll version you used and which one fixed the issue for you.

Comment: At first I used QT version 5.7.0. There were only binary folders like winrt_x86/x64/arm_msvc2015. Now I installed QT version 5.8.0. There is a binary folder named msvc2015_64, which solved my problem.

Comment: ok, you linked the Qt files for store apps not for desktop, that why you got the message.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Both Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp) and Visual Studio 2015 (v140) is now working together with Target Platform 8.1 under Windows 7

Comment: if the question is answered [you can accept my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.